# SQL*Loader-522: lfiopn failed for file error

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, sql-loader

I am getting below error in my script which is running a SQLLDR :

```
SQL*Loader-522: lfiopn failed for file (Testfile1.log)
```

[image]

Table Creation on Sqlplus :-

[image]

below is the SQLLDR command :

```
>sqlldr userid=hr/hr

control =  D:\Oracle\Testfile1.ctl
```

below is the control file temp :

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE '‪D:\Oracle\File1.txt'
insert
into table target
fields terminated by ','
optionally enclosed by ','
trailing nullcols
(emp_id, emp_name, salary )
```

Request you to help me to resolve the error.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have privileges to create SQL*Loader's **log file** in that directory. Which one is it? Seems to be root of the `C` disk (as you're running `sqlldr` while located in there).

I'd suggest you to explicitly specify log file; as control file resides in `D:\Oracle\`, use it:

```
sqlldr hr/hr control=D:\Oracle\Testfile1.ctl log=D:\Oracle\Testfile1.log
                                             ---------------------------
                                             this
```

Comment: Thanx for the quick response..Folder have all the rights to create folder. And i have tried which you have shared but getting same error.